# how to get a variable value from form to python function in django from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms

I am trying to scan QR code using javascript as shown below. this part is working fine:

```
<title>Django Online Barcode Reader</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 
{% csrf_token %}

<script src={% static "html5-qrcode.min.js"%}></script>
<style>
.result{
background-color: green;
color:#fff;
padding:20px;
}
.row{
display:flex;
}
</style>

<!--<form action="" method="POST">-->
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<div style="width:500px;" id="reader"></div>
</div>
<div class="col" style="padding:30px;">
<h4>SCAN RESULT</h4>
<!--<div id="result" name="result">Result Here</div>-->
<output type="post" id="result" name="resutl" placeholder="qrCodeMessage">
  
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onScanSuccess(qrCodeMessage) {
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<span class="result">'+qrCodeMessage+'</span>';}

function onScanError(errorMessage) {
//handle scan error
}

var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
"reader", { fps: 10, qrbox: 250 });
html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess, onScanError);
</script>
```

But I need to pass the value of result variable to python function as following and print it but did not work. It does not print any!

```
def userspage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.POST.get("result")
        context = {}
        print(result)
        return render(request, 'users.html', context)
```

I need your usual help to fix this. Thanks,

Comment: make sure that u are calling the function in your urls.py file

Comment: the function is called in the url.py under same view of the app.                              from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', views.userspage, name="users"),
]

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in line

```
<output type="post" id="result" name="resutl" placeholder="qrCodeMessage">
```

change it to `name="result"`